# jQuery Swap data with Select Drop Down

Tags: jquery, select, input

Quite new to jQuery and for the life of me cannot workout why this won't work ..

```
<script> 
    jQuery('#my-quantity').change(function() {
    jQuery('#my-button').data('item-quantity', jQuery(this).val());}
</script>

<button class="snipcart-add-item" id="my-button" data-item-id="1" data-item-url="/"
    data-item-name="Item" data-item-price="20.00" data-item-quantity="">
   Buy now
</button>
<select id="my-quantity">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you indicate what the expected behaviour is and in what way isn't it working. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Take the jQuery down below the html and add it before the ending `body` tag which is `</body>`

```
 $(document).on('change','#my-quantity', function() {
   $('#my-button').data('item-quantity', $(this).val());
 });
```

Replaced `jQuery` with `$` you can use `jQuery` as well.

Comment: I think it might be because the resulting text has to be a number ...which I know it is ... but is it text rather than a numerical ?

Comment: @KylePaige Any errors in console. It can select text as well so the error is somewhere else. May be if you can create a fiddle?